# jQuery Focus on Click

Tags: jquery, input, click, focus

On click, I'm trying to put focus on an input field. I thought it would be as easy as:

```
jQuery('li a').on('click', function() {
    jQuery('input.s').focus();
});
```

However, the search input field is NOT getting focused. I'm thinking it's because the input field is in a popup (actually, a div that gets unhidden when a link is clicked). What adjustments do I need to make to properly target the input field so it does get focused when the link is clicked?

### HTML

```
<div class="fusion-custom-menu-item-contents" style="display: block;"><form role="search" class="searchform" method="get" action="">
    <div class="search-table">
        <div class="search-field">
            <input type="text" value="" name="s" class="s" placeholder="Search ...">
        </div>
        <div class="search-button">
            <input type="submit" class="searchsubmit" value="">
        </div>
    </div>
</form></div>
```

### CSS

```
element.style {
    display: block;
}
/media="all"
#menu-global-header-menu-1 > li.fusion-custom-menu-item.fusion-main-menu-search.fusion-last-menu-item.fusion-main-menu-search-open > div {
    display: block !important;
}
.fusion-main-menu .fusion-main-menu-cart .fusion-custom-menu-item-contents, .fusion-main-menu .fusion-main-menu-search .fusion-custom-menu-item-contents, .fusion-main-menu .fusion-menu-login-box .fusion-custom-menu-item-contents {
    background-color: #f2efef;
    border-color: #dcdadb;
}
/media="all"
.fusion-main-menu .fusion-main-menu-search-open .fusion-custom-menu-item-contents {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}
/media="all"
.fusion-main-menu .fusion-main-menu-search .fusion-custom-menu-item-contents {
    display: none;
    width: 250px;
    padding: 25px;
    text-align: right;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
}
.fusion-main-menu .fusion-custom-menu-item-contents {
    font-family: 'Raleway', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
}
/media="all"
.fusion-main-menu .fusion-custom-menu-item-contents {
    /* position: absolute; */
    /* left: auto; */
    /* right: 0; */
    /* visibility: hidden; */
    /* opacity: 0; */
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in;
    /* transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in; */
}
/media="all"
* {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
user agent stylesheetdiv {
    display: block;
}
Inherited from 
user agent stylesheetli {
    display: list-item;
    text-align: -webkit-match-parent;
}
Inherited from 
/media="all"
.fusion-main-menu ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
user agent stylesheetul, menu, dir {
    display: block;
    list-style-type: disc;
    -webkit-margin-before: 1em;
    -webkit-margin-after: 1em;
    -webkit-margin-start: 0px;
    -webkit-margin-end: 0px;
    -webkit-padding-start: 40px;
}
Inherited from 
/media="all"
.fusion-row {
    margin: 0 auto;
    zoom: 1;
}
Inherited from 
#reviews #comments > h2, #wrapper .fusion-tabs-widget .tab-holder .news-list li .post-holder .meta, #wrapper .meta, .fusion-blog-timeline-layout .fusion-timeline-date, .fusion-rollover .price .amount, .post .post-content, .post-content blockquote, .project-content .project-info h4, .quantity .minus, .quantity .plus, .quantity .qty, .review blockquote div, .search input, .sidebar .jtwt, .sidebar .widget .recentcomments, .sidebar .widget_archive li, .sidebar .widget_categories li, .sidebar .widget_links li, .sidebar .widget_meta li, .sidebar .widget_nav_menu li, .sidebar .widget_pages li, .sidebar .widget_recent_entries li, .title-row, body {
    color: #747474;
}
#side-header .fusion-contact-info, #side-header .header-social .top-menu, #slidingbar-area .slide-excerpt h2, .fusion-accordian .panel-body, .fusion-footer-widget-area .slide-excerpt h2, .post-content blockquote, .project-content .project-info h4, .review blockquote q, .sidebar .slide-excerpt h2, body {
    line-height: 26px;
}
#slidingbar-area .slide-excerpt h2, .fusion-footer-widget-area .slide-excerpt h2, .jtwt .jtwt_tweet, .sidebar .jtwt .jtwt_tweet, .sidebar .slide-excerpt h2, body {
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 27px;
}
#nav ul li ul li a, #reviews #comments > h2, #sticky-nav ul li ul li a, #wrapper #nav ul li ul li > a, #wrapper #sticky-nav ul li ul li > a, .avada-container h3, .comment-form input[type="submit"], .ei-title h3, .fusion-blog-shortcode .fusion-timeline-date, .fusion-image-wrapper .fusion-rollover .fusion-rollover-content .fusion-rollover-categories, .fusion-image-wrapper .fusion-rollover .fusion-rollover-content .fusion-rollover-title, .fusion-image-wrapper .fusion-rollover .fusion-rollover-content .price, .fusion-image-wrapper .fusion-rollover .fusion-rollover-content a, .fusion-load-more-button, .fusion-page-title-bar h3, .meta .fusion-date, .more, .post-content blockquote, .project-content .project-info h4, .review blockquote div strong, .review blockquote q, .ticket-selector-submit-btn[type="submit"], body {
    font-family: 'Raleway', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
}
/media="all"
body {
    margin: 0;
    color: #747474;
    min-width: 320px;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    font: 13px/20px 'PTSansRegular', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: when is the popup opening?

Comment: can you post related html and css?, it would be better to solve

Comment: Rejith: the popup is opening when "li a" is clicked.

Comment: can you add the code for that here?

Comment: Hey guys, I went ahead and added the HTML/CSS.

Comment: okay, where is `li a` selector as you mentioned in script?

Comment: Sathish, it's in: #menu-global-header-menu-1 > li a. The HTML shown above is the location of the input field I'm trying to put focus on.

Comment: Do you have any error in the browser's console? Try to put `alert('clicked')` before `jQuery('input.s').focus();` to be sure the `click`  is fired.

Comment: when click, you need to open a popup then focus right?

Comment: kulaeff: there is no error in the browser console and when I added alert('clicked') it did execute

Comment: Add `return false;` after `jQuery('input.s').focus();`

Answer (score 0):

As you mention script working fine , i think when you click `a` selector it will moved to given url in `href`.

so use [preventDefault](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) event, it will not take the browser to a new URL

```js
jQuery('#menu-global-header-menu-1 > li > a').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
jQuery('.fusion-custom-menu-item-contents').find('input.s').focus();
});
```

```css
.fusion-custom-menu-item-contents {
border: 1px solid;
padding: 46px;
width: 150px;
}
input:focus{
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 
<ul id="menu-global-header-menu-1">
  <li><a href="#">click here to focus</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="fusion-custom-menu-item-contents" style="display: block;">
<form role="search" class="searchform" method="get" action="">
<div class="search-table">
    <div class="search-field">
        <input type="text" value="" name="s" class="s" placeholder="Search ...">
    </div>
    <div class="search-button">
        <input type="submit" class="searchsubmit" value="">
    </div>
</div>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: @rick try this `jQuery('#menu-global-header-menu-1 > li.fusion-main-menu-search').on('click', function() {
    jQuery('.fusion-custom-menu-item-contents').show().find('input.s').focus();
});`

Comment: Then  you missing something to mention here

Answer (score -1):

The simplest way to focus your input field is to set attribute "autofocus"

```
<input type="text" value="" name="s" class="s" placeholder="Search" autofocus="autofocus">
```

The field is by default focused.

I tried it on your page and it works :)

Comment: Please read OP's title, OP wants focus when clicked, not focus by default.

Comment: @DanielCheung it doesnt matter if the "path to the goal"is by clicking or by the default behavior(autofocused). KISS = Keep it simple, stupid :)

Comment: **\*facepalm**, OP wanted the input to get focused when you click a `li a`. That means, when you click away and get the input unfocused, when you click the `li a`, the input become focused again. This code does not do that.